# Can I ask my contractor to redo a tile job I'm not happy with?

Tags: bathroom, tile

[image: floor tile - notice broken hex pattern]

*Click on photo for full size*

I had my bathroom renovated while I was away last week. I'm not happy with how the floor tile came out. I assumed the contractor would lay the tile out in a uniform way (yes I know-- ass-u-me).

The bathroom is pretty small- about 4 1/2 feet by 5 feet of total floor space (plus bathtub). I thought I could live with this-- but it is kind of driving me nuts.

Two questions--

- is it fair to have him redo it?And how tough would it be to redo it.
  I have a bunch of left over tile so I wouldn't need to buy much more.
- How tough is it to rip the tile out and redo it. There are no
  moldings or anything. The only thing which would need to be removed
  aside from the tile is the toilet.
- Ok three questions-- what do you think the cost of this should be (I
  live in Manhattan).

[image: photo with toilet in place]

just to be clear-- here is an updated photo when the job was completed. I wanted to make clear that the issue was not the white spots or grout-- the issue was how the pattern was not continuous and how the seams are shown between the sheets of tile.

Comment: Wow. That's a terrible tile job. Did you already pay him? If so, you can certainly ask/demand he redo it but that might be an uphill battle.

Comment: I got to say, that bathroom tile (and bathroom in general) looks rode hard and put away wet. I might expect this kind of work from a complete amateur but a professional contractor has no business charging anybody for this shameful display. I would demand my money back and look for somebody else to redo it. Threaten to report him to the Better Business Bureau and give negative ratings on Google, Angies List and just about every other site if he does not comply. If that isn't enough then threaten to take him to small claims.

Comment: @DA01- see updated photo-- I wanted to be clear that the issue was with the layout of the pattern.

Comment: @maple_shaft - it's a bit tricky-- because I have become friendly with contractor over the years-- but this was disappointing. I'm sure he will be unhappy when he realizes I'm unhappy-- but sometimes it's difficult for folks to admit when they've screwed up. I also wanted you to see updated photo-- the one I had posted was before tile was grouted. Does that change anything for you?

Comment: Yes, that is a totally unprofessional job.

Comment: Wow, looking at it actually hurts my eyes.  I am not kidding.

Comment: This person makes money at this?  Wow.  Just wow.  I could have done a better job when I was the fifth grade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't really answer the cost or any legal questions (OT per our FAQ), but it's unanimous that this job was done poorly. Repairing it right will likely involve removing everything and starting over from scratch. There's not enough benefit in saving a few rows of tile and it would make the thin set and grout work more difficult. Ripping up the floor in the bathroom is more difficult the better your contractor did their job. A power chisel will make the job go faster, but no matter how you do it, it will be a mess.

I'd point out the mistakes, ask him to correct it, and if he refuses, never work with that contractor again. A good contractor is willing to fix their mistakes and make the customer happy, since a good reference is usually worth more than the materials and labor.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I wanted to comment. I had a licensed landscaper extend my existing retaining wall about 20 ft. x 6 ft. His crew did a really shoddy job. I was in disbelief. Mortar was applied unevenly, sloppy and too thick, the vertical seams weren't aligned properly and horizontally the blocks appeared to wave. The wall leaned slightly as if the footing hadn't cured, and a few blocks were loose and not even cemented. I contacted the contractor and asked him to come out to take a look at the mess. He did. He agreed it was a lousy job. I didn't have to ask, he suggested it be torn down and rebuilt. I guess I could have told him to take a hike before he made the suggestion, but since he was straightforward and didn't try to sugarcoat anything, I gave it another chance. It was done nearly perfectly the second time. So yes, contractors will and should remedy the job to the client's satisfaction by doing whatever it takes to get it done right. I have learned to hire licensed ones because you do have recourse if there are problems, and don't give them a deposit anymore than what is legal, usually 10%.